# EdgeJS calls in C# Web API causing AccessViolation Exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, edgejs

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using EdgeJs;

namespace edge2.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        public async Task<object> Get(int id)
        {
            var func = Edge.Func(@"
            return function (data, callback) {
                callback(null, 'Node.js welcomes ' + data);
            }
            ");
            return await func(".NET");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm looking at trying to call *node.js* from *C#*. I have the above example code that is documented on their [GitHub page](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge), but when the code is moved over to a C# Web API project I get a consistent error.
`AccessViolation Exception`. The error only happens on the first run, and only after a rebuild of the project. All subsequent runs work perfectly.

Tooling:
VS2015
.NET 4.5.2
EdgeJS 4.0.0

Comment: I experience the same error when i stop and build and execute my project. Any updates?

Comment: No solutions at the moment. currently we are using Jint (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Jint), although I'm wanting to try and get a proper ffi to nodejs, which edjejs seems to be solving.

Comment: Have you seen this issue? https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge/issues/383